# Pick specific timepoints from a timeseries

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a **164 x 246 matrix** called **M**. **M** is data for time series containing 246 time points of 164 brain regions. I want to work on only specific blocks of the time series, not the whole thing. To do so, I created a vector called onsets containing the time onset of each block.

```
onsets = [7;37;82;112;145;175;190;220];
```

In this example, there are 8 blocks total (though this number can vary), each blocks containing 9 time points. So for instance, the first block would contain time point 7, 8, 9,..., 15; the second block would contain time point 37, 38, 39,..., 45. I would like to extract the time points for these 8 blocks from **M** and concatenate 8 these blocks. Thus, the output should be a **164 x 72** matrix (i.e., 164 regions, 8 blocks x 9 time points/per block).

This seems like a very simple indexing problem but I'm struggling to do this efficiently. I've tried indexing each block in M (for intance, `vertcat(M(onsets(1,1):onsets(1,1)+8,:));`) then use `vertcat` but this seems very clumsy. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you want to use `vertcat` on one matrix `M(onsets(1,1):onsets(1,1)+8,:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
% create sample data
M       = rand(164,246);

% create index vector
idx     = false(1,size(M,2));
onsets  = [7;37;82;112;145;175;190;220];

for i=1:numel(onsets)
    idx(onsets(i):onsets(i)+8) = true;
end

% create output matrix
MM      = M(:,idx);
```

You seem to have switched the dimensions somehow, i.e. you try to operate on the rows of `M` whilst according to your description you need to operate on the columns. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I had to changed the dimension `idx     = false(size(M,1),1);` and `MM      = M(idx,:);` but this is likely because I didn't explain my question well. Cheers!